# Syntax for referencing methods in Dart?

Tags: dart

Dart supports referencing static functions, but is there a syntax to reference methods on objects as well, similar to Java/Kotlin?

```dart
[1, -3, 5].map((n) => n.abs()).forEach(print); // this works...
[1, -3, 5].map(int::abs).forEach(print); // ...but this won't compile
```

Comment: You need an instance to reference an instance member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I said before that Dart can't do what you're trying to do, as in order to call an instance method you need an instance. That said, what you're doing is reminiscent of a Javascript coding style and isn't very idiomatic for Dart. I'd suggest the following instead:

```dart
final list = [1, -3, 5];
for (var n in list) {
  print(n.abs());
}
```

or

```dart
final list = [1, -3, 5].map((n) => n.abs());
for (var n in list) {
  print(n);
}
```

The `forEach` method isn't strictly recommended unless you have a pre-existing method you can pass in. Otherwise, it tends to make the code a bit denser and thus harder to read at a glance. (And this isn't Javascript, you don't need to worry about scope or closure issues when using a regular old for loop.)

**EDIT:**

There is a possible workaround, though I'm not sure I see much point in doing it this way unless it tickles a particular kind of fancy. You can "wrap" the call to the instance method within a local anonymous method, then pass the reference of *that* method to, in your case, the `map` method:

```dart
int abs(int i) => i.abs();
[1, -3, 5].map(abs).forEach(print);
```

In practice, this effectively just breaks the lambda method you created in your first example out into a method in its own right, so there's an argument to be made that this approach succeeds only in making the process more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: The example above is contrived, and just meant to show how we can reference static functions in Dart, but (apparently) not methods (yet?).

Comment: @ejain You can reference instance methods, just not in the way you are hoping. For instance, you can store a reference to `n.abs` and call it later. But rather than being a general reference to the instance method `abs`, it will be a reference to that _specific instance's `abs` method_. As such, calling it would return the same value as though you had just called `n.abs()` directly.

Comment: What you're asking for isn't the ability to store a reference to an instance method, but rather the ability to call a particular method on an instance merely by passing in the name of the method as though it was a method reference. This isn't possible to my knowledge, but a workaround would be to write a helper method that "wraps" the call. I'll edit in an example of this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mentioned earlier, you still need an instance to reference. If you're looking for means to shorten your code, you might want to use
`[1, -3, 5].forEach((f) => print(f.abs()));`

Comment: Trying to make the code more readable, not shorter ;-) Incidentally, Effective Dart doesn't like the passing of function literals to forEach, see https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal...

Comment: Oh, that's true - you're right. I might just go for this:

`[1, -3, 5].forEach(printAbs);`
    
`void printAbs(num value){
       print(value.abs());
}`

Comment: @ejain Effective Dart doesn't like function literals for `forEach` because it becomes a direct equivalent of a `for in` loop except more verbose.